# Can't create full screen

Tags: android, xml

I'm learning Android from this tutorials:

http://gamecodeschool.com/android-projects/ but there is one problem. In some games you need to set full screen resolution in XML file. I'm doing correct with the tutorial but my game crashes when I'm installing it on a device. It's just because this XML file. I'm quite annoyed and I tried learning on my own but still I have always bugs with this full screen. Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this

- Simply by programmaming

---

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

---

- Or you can do it via your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

---

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

---

- If you are using AppCompatActivity then you need to set theme as below

---

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

---

- Customize by its own create this in `styles.xml`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
<style name="theme_fullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Black"> 
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style> 
</resources>
```

---

Comment: first way work, thanks you so much, i have used similar lines of code but i dont know why they werent work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

**way 1**.set in the manifest

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

**way 2**.set in the java code

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // add this before setContentView methood ,and after super
   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 

   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);  

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

**way 3**.set in the manifest and set in the style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
    <style name="theme_fullScreen" parent="android:Theme.Black"> 
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style> 
</resources>
```

in the manifest

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@style/theme_fullScreen"/>
```

**Note**

- change the `android:theme` of the `Activity`.
- set `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct but I am providing a solution which I'm using and even on a notification or any other focus change, it remains as it is or comes back to its original state.

Put this in your activity

- Declare this Variable

  ```
  private int currentApiVersion;
  ```
- Put this in onCreate

  ```
  currentApiVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
  if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
      final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
              if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                  decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
              }
          }
      });
  }
  ```
- And this method below onCreate

  ```
  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
      if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
          getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                          |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      }
  }
  ```

This will give you the best fullscreen activity just like a game activity.